# Excel RTD Server Development in C++

Tags: c++, excel, finance, rtd

I want to write an excel RTD server in C++ but have not yet had any luck finding and complete tutorials on how to do so aside from this http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2008/12/02/Rtd5.aspx.

However, as I am new to this stuff, I think I need something more complete. Can any of you point me in the direction of a C++ example?

Thanks

EDIT: for those interested, I found this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/245265/Guide-to-Writing-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-Part-II.aspx

Comment: Excel RTD is "just a COM server" implementing the interface Excel wants... if you are lloking for components to make the implementation easier a good start is http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/excel-rtd-servers.php

Comment: Thanks, Yahai. I'm hoping to keep it in the C++ realm for now and minimise the COM stuff to wrappers for other processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Guide-to-Writing-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-Part-II](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/245265/Guide-to-Writing-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-Part-II) details the process in full